# How to add a component of randomness to a schedule

Tags: python, random, jobs, schedule

I am trying to schedule a job to run every 3 minutes on average, with a component of randomness between +/- 30 seconds. So the next job runs anywhere between 2mins 30secs - 3mins 30secs later.

This code works nicely for exactly 3 minutes, but I can't think of a way to introduce the 30 secs of randomness:

```
import schedule
def job:
   print('hi')

schedule.every(3).minutes.do(job)
```

Comment: you can refer python docs for `import random`.

[Python Random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

Comment: and how would I insert it into the code?

Comment: Did you mean: `schedule.every(150 + random.randint(0 ,60)).seconds.do(job)`?

Comment: use a random value between 0 to 60 seconds and it to 2.5 minutes.

@quamrana You should push it to the answers.

Comment: "and how would I insert it into the code?" Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look up the `random` module that comes with python.

```py
import schedule
import random

def job():
   print('hi')

two_mins_30 = 2 * 60 + 30
schedule.every(two_mins_30 + random.randint(0, 60)).seconds.do(job)
```

This calculation is: two minutes, 30 plus up to another minute at random.

**Update:**

It turns out you can directly do this with `schedule` because the `Job` class has a `to()` method:

```py
schedule.every(two_mins_30).to(two_mins_30 + 60).seconds.do(job)
```

Comment: But won't that just make a random number once at the beginning, so it will always be 150 seconds + say 26 secs and do that all day?

Comment: Ok, yes. Better have a think about that.